# My sql finding the median not able to understand the query is executing

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that there are other queries already given to find the median but I want to know how this query is working

Select round(S.LAT_N,4) median from TEST.meadian S  where  (select count(Lat_N) from TEST.meadian where Lat_N > S.LAT_N ) =  (select count(Lat_N) from TEST.meadian WHERE Lat_N > S.LAT_N);

If their are total 449 rows than this query returns 448

```
Select round(S.LAT_N,4) median from TEST.meadian S  where  (select count(Lat_N) from TEST.meadian where Lat_N > S.LAT_N );
```

If there are total 449 rows than this query returns 448

```
Select round(S.LAT_N,4) median from TEST.meadian S  where  (select count(Lat_N) from TEST.meadian where Lat_N < S.LAT_N )
```

Then how it is finding median fro a given for odd no of rows.

Comment: @tim-biegeleisenn i know there are other queries to find the median But i am not able to understand how this query works if you can please explain it